# React call setState from inside Socket.emit('event', arg, (response) => {this.setState()}); doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react using cdn with flask backend and i want to do something like this:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
    state = {
        count: 0
    }
    redirect = '';

    get_sess_id() {
        let id = document.getElementById("sess_id").value;
        
        clientSocket.emit("message", {id: id}, (response) => {
            console.log(this);
            this.redirect = id;
            this.setState({
                count: this.state.count + 1
            });
        });
        document.getElementById("sess_id").value = "";
    }

    render() {
        var red;
        if (this.state.count) {
            red = <ReactRouterDOM.Redirect to="/message/{this.redirect}"/>;
            this.state.count = 0;
        }else{
            red = null;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                { red }
                <div className='content-section'>
                    <input className='form-control' id="sess_id"></input>
                    <button className='btn btn-outline-info' onClick={this.get_sess_id}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I'm new to js and react. it seems the callback function is on a different scope and i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
```

How do i get around this?

the backend look something like this:

```
@socketio.on('message')
def verify_connect_request(data):
    if data['id'] in user_list:    #where user list is list of currently connected users
        return True
```

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? We can't guess what exactly is wrong with your code. Do you get any errors? Unexpected behavior? What is the intended behavior?

Comment: i want to do setState() if the response is true, but apparently the callback fuction is on a different scope and i can't access the class variables or attributes inside it.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Comment: provide a [mre] and take a look at [ask]. your component doesn't do anything as of now.

Comment: Use MobX for state management!!